# Remove horizontal shadow of Material widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

After adding `elevation` to `Material` widget, I want to keep only the bottom shadow. Don't want the left and right side shadow. How to achieve this?

Here is my code :

```
        // searchbar
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            color: AppColors.searchBoxColor,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                // searchfield
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Hint Text",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: ok can you provide some replicable code and some image what would show what exactly you mean?

Comment: @LonelyWolf I have added code. I just want to remove horizontal shadow that I get after adding elevation property.

Comment: Hi @Newaj. I've updated my answer applying the shadow with your code. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with `elevation` because that will inevitably cast the shadows as if a piece of paper is elevated in air.

What you can do is to add a custom shadow using a `BoxShadow`. If you're using a `RaisedButton`, for example, you can change to use a `FlatButton` with a `Container` with a `BoxDecoration`. Here is an example of that:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Button With Elevation'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {},
                elevation: 12.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 32.0,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Button With Custom Shadow'),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image: Button with elevation vs button with custom shadow]

By specifying the values of your `Offset` you can change the direction to where the shadow will cast.

UPDATE:

I saw your code later. Here is how you implement `BoxShadow` with your code:

```
child: Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 0.0,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: AppColors.searchBoxColor,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          offset: Offset(0.0, 12.0),
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
          blurRadius: 5.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "Hint Text",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the shadow using the boxShadow property of the Container, here an example:

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          offset: Offset(0, 5),
          blurRadius: 5,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
     ],
   ),
 ),
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But what about the Material widget?

Comment: Based on what I saw in the documentation it is not possible to change the elevation shadow with the properties of Material.